# Swift - get UIImage from UIView using 3D transform

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm working on an app to edit images. The "editor" have a squared `UIView`, and this view have some subviews:

- A background `UIImageView`;
- One or more overlays with 3d Transform. These views can be `UITextView` or `UIImageView`.

So, when the user is ready to save the image, I calculate how bigger than original `UIView` the image should be to have the same size of the original background image.

For example: if the background image is 3750x3750 and the user is using an iPhone X (so the wrapper `UIView` is 375x375), my final scale will be 10.

So, I need to get a scaled image from this `UIView`. What I tried so far:

**1 - Using `view.drawHierarchy(in: context)`:**

If I use a context with the same size of the `UIView` (in my example 375x375) with a scale of 10, final image will be pixelated. Actually the result is the same no matter which scale I use.

I tried to up scale my `UIView` to the final size before to call the `drawHierarchy(in:)` method using a scale 1, but this is not safe: works for small images, but bigger images will make the app crash with a memory warning.

**2 - Using `view.layer.render(in: context)`:**

Using a context with the `UIView` size and the calculated scale needed, this will render a image with the right resolution, without pixelate, but all my 3D transformations will be discarded.

In all cases I'm updating the `layer.contentScale` of all subviews (and its subviews and sublayers) accordingly.

So, I need to use the `drawHierarchy(in:)` method respecting the calculated scale OR use the `view.layer.render(in:)` method respecting the 3D transformation of the subviews.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Adding some code instead of describing it could make things clearer.

Comment: view.layer.render(in: context) is the way to go. Can you post a sample of your transform method and how you capture the Graphic context?

Comment: Did u solve the issue? can u plz tell the solution